# Не работает ввод любых символов кроме пробела в TextBox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Создаю обычный `TextBox` на форме

При запуске формы я не могу ничего ввести в этот TextBox, кроме пробела.
Никак не могу понять из-за чего это. В чем может быть проблема?

Проект выгрузил в облако https://yadi.sk/d/ak2YVw673AyMSg

```
<Window x:Class="CommentsMaker.View.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:CommentsMaker"
    xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:CommentsMaker.ViewModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="600" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
<Window.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainWindowViewModel/>
</Window.DataContext>
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Styles\StyleButton.xaml"/>
</Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Column="1">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition Height="10"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="10"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Text="File name prefix:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBox Name="TbFileName" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25"
                 Text="{Binding GetNameDocument, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Text="Select discipine code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" Text="Select discrepancy code:" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Left"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DisciplineCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Desc"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDiscipline}"/>
        <ComboBox Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="25"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding DiscrepansyCollection}" DisplayMemberPath="Desc"
                  SelectedValue="{Binding SelectedDiscrepancy}"/>
        <RichTextBox Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="3" Grid.RowSpan="2"></RichTextBox>
    </Grid>
    <StackPanel>
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MainButton}" Content="CREATE COMMENT" Command="{Binding CreateCommentCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <Button Style="{StaticResource MainButton}" Content="UPDATE COMMENT" Command="{Binding AddTabCommand}" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
        <TextBox />
    </StackPanel>



</Grid>
```

Класс MainVindowViewModel:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using CommentsMaker.MVVM;
using JetBrains.Annotations;
namespace CommentsMaker.ViewModel
{
    class MainWindowViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        #region Properties
        public Data SelectedDiscipline
        {
            get => _selectedDiscipline;
            set
            {
                _selectedDiscipline = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public Data SelectedDiscrepancy
        {
            get => _selectedDiscrepancy;
            set
            {
                _selectedDiscrepancy = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
        public ObservableCollection<Data> DisciplineCollection
        {
            get => _disciplineCollection;
            set
            {
                _disciplineCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }

        }
        public ObservableCollection<Data> DiscrepansyCollection
        {
            get => _discrepansyCollection;
            set
            {
                _discrepansyCollection = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        public string GetNameDocument
        {
            get => _getNameDocument;
            set
            {
                _getNameDocument = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        #endregion

        #region Fields

        private Data _selectedDiscipline;
        private Data _selectedDiscrepancy;
        private ObservableCollection<Data> _disciplineCollection;
        private ObservableCollection<Data> _discrepansyCollection;
        private string _getNameDocument;

        private ICommand _createComment;


        #endregion


        #region Commands

        public ICommand CreateCommentCommand
        {
            get
            {
                return _createComment ?? (_createComment = new RelayCommand(x => { CreateComment(); }));
            }
        }

        #endregion

        #region Private method

        private void CreateComment()
        {
            try
            {
                MessageBox.Show(GetNameDocument);

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
            }

        }
        #endregion


        #region MVVM
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
        #endregion
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        //public override string ToString()
        //{
        //    return Name + ", " + Desc;
        //}
    }

}
```

Comment: Уберите `Name="TbFileName"` и запустите. Запускается? Если нет, то вы что то нам еще не показали. Стандартный `TextBox` подобной ерундой не страдает!

Comment: Name="TbFileName"  я уже после поставил. Сейчас обновлю. Закину весь код.

Comment: Хорошо, создайте тогда чистый WPF проект и добавьте в него просто `<TextBox/>` и попробуйте написать в него нужный текст. Если напишет, то вы опять же что то нам не договариваете. Если нет, то у вас явно проблема с Windows или что то мешает это сделать.

Comment: Думаю, для начала имеет смысл глянуть вот на это `GetNameDocument` отсюда `Text="{Binding GetNameDocument....`

Comment: В новом документе работает нормально.

Comment: GetNameDocument  я тоже убирал, но это не помогло

Comment: Ну раз в новом все работает, то вы что то нам не договариваете и не показываете. Может у вас есть стиль какой то, может у вас переопределен TextBox, может где то вы его подписываете на какое то событие, нам к сожалению этого не узнать. Так что ищите то, что делает ваш TextBox не стандартным и потом уже мы попробуем вам помочь.

Comment: Еще, изначально я создавал проект как  Приложение Windows, потом его переделал в Библиотеку классов, может ли интересно повлиять этот момент?

Comment: @user275841 нет

Comment: поищите по всему проекту `TbFileName` и покажите все места, где это используется.

Comment: Я его не использую, я добавил его только в разметку, в попытке понять, что из-за него проблема. Дело в том что такая же проблема и с RichBox, который находится в самом низу. Я его нигде еще не использовал.

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема. Я окно вызываю window.Show() и не вводится. Если я поменяю на window.ShowDialog(), то все работает. Но мне нужно именно Show(). Здесь нужно использовать потоки как я понимаю?

Comment: Это тоже не может влиять. У меня как минимум 10 проектов, которые вызывают MainWindow через window.Show(); и что то с текстовыми полями все норм.

Comment: Я пишу что то вроде плагина для программы и соответственно запускаю это окно по кнопке из программы, может из-за этого